# WPF flowdocument block padding

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is the best way to adjust the distance between blocks in a flowdocument?

I'm adding blocks to a flowdocument in code-behind. Assuming `flowDoc` is an instance of `FlowDocument` that is ready to go, I add a block with:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add("Hello there");
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
```

If I run this multiple times, it adds a new block each time. How do I adjust the distance between blocks?

Changing the [`Paragraph.Padding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.padding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property seems to change padding for items within the `Paragraph`, not between `Paragraphs` in the `Block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after digging around some more, I realized I need to use the `Margin` property of `Paragraph`, not the `Padding` property of `Blocks`. Let me explain.

In the WPF guide on MSDN, there is a section titled ["Alignment, Margins, and Padding Overview"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the "Layout" section. It states:

> The Margin property describes the distance between an element and its child **or peers.** [emphasis added]

So, instead of thinking about how to adjust spacing between *child* elements using `Padding`, I can adjust spacing between *peers* using `Margin`. Here's how it would look in code-behind:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add("Hello there");
// adjust spacing between paragraphs with Margin property
para.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5, 1, 1, 5);
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
```

...and, here's how to adjust margin in XAML:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph Name="newPara" Margin="5,1,1,5">
        Hello There
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```